# Android ListView, OnListItemClick, find row id?

Tags: android

I cant seem to find out how to get my ListView (OnListItemClick), to open different activity´s. I know i somehow need to get some row-id for my ListView, but i dont know how to. Right now every row in my ListView just opens up the same activity. 
Sorry for my bad English, hope You understand.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;

static final String[] title = new String[] {
"Text", 
"Text", 
"Text",
;

static final String[] detail = new String[] {
"Image1",
"Image2",
"Image3",
};

private Integer[] imgid = {
R.drawable.spektr,
R.drawable.spektr,
R.drawable.sleep,



};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
data = new Vector<RowData>();
for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){

try {
rd = new RowData(i,title[i],detail[i]);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
data.add(rd);
}
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,
                              R.id.title, data);
setListAdapter(adapter);
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                                                         long id) {         

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", item.mId);
  startActivity(intent);

}
private class RowData {
protected int mId;
protected String mTitle;
protected String mDetail;
RowData(int id,String title,String detail){
mId=id;
mTitle = title;
mDetail=detail;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
        return mId+" "+mTitle+" "+mDetail;
}
}
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                 int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {               

super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

ViewHolder holder = null;
TextView title = null;
TextView detail = null;
ImageView i11=null;
RowData rowData= getItem(position);
if(null == convertView){
     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
     convertView.setTag(holder);
}
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      title = holder.gettitle();
      title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
      detail = holder.getdetail();
      detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);                                                     

      i11=holder.getImage();
      i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
      return convertView;
}
     private class ViewHolder {
     private View mRow;
     private TextView title = null;
     private TextView detail = null;
     private ImageView i11=null; 

     public ViewHolder(View row) {
     mRow = row;
}
  public TextView gettitle() {
      if(null == title){
          title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
         }
     return title;
  }     

  public TextView getdetail() {
      if(null == detail){
           detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
             }
    return detail;
  }
 public ImageView getImage() {
      if(null == i11){
           i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
                               }
         return i11;
 }
 }

 }
}
```

And my NewActivity looks like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.poetry);

    getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to get the "row ID of the `ListView`", you need to get the "row ID of the *item* that was clicked in the `Listview`"

Luckily, Android gives you the row ID right there as the last parameter of `onListItemClick()`, where you're currently using the position:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
  // intent.putExtra("position", position); // not what you want
  intent.putExtra("id", id); // more likely what you want
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you do not have an ID, you can also get the actual item, i.e. a `RowData` object in your case, from the `ListAdapter`:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
  RowData item = (RowData) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("id", item.mId);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

In both cases, you have to change your code in `NewActity` so you extract the ID, not position, from the extra bundle.

**Another update:**

> Lets say my list have 10 items, item 1, item 2, item 3 and so on. When item 1 is clicked i want that to open a new activity, let's call that NewActivityOne, and NewActivityOne will refer to a layout with some text called layoutone. Item 2 will also open a new activity, NewActivityTwo, which will refer to a new layout called layouttwo. And that's how I want it to be for all my items.

- If your detail activities differ *only in the layout* (i.e. not in any behavior/code), just use `putExtra()` to pass an `R.layout.*` ID (let's call it "layoutId") to your `NewActivity` and use that in `setContentView(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("layoutId"));`.
- If your detail activities differ *more widely*, create a separate `Activity` class for every list item, and in `onListItemClick()` create an `Intent` with the respestive activity class you want to display.

In either case, you can store the details to display (`int layoutId` or `Class<Activity>`) in your `RowData` class so you can easily access it in `onListItemClick()`.

Comment: Okay I see. But I dont understand where to find the "id". Is it somewhere to be found in my java-file, like a number or what?

Comment: You would usually get an ID from a [`(Simple)CursorAdapter`](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#cursor), which in turn takes things from a database. If you really only need a fixed number of items as you do now, you could ignore the ID and instead get the clicked list item from the `ListAdapter` -- I updated my answer for a way to do this :)

Comment: It's the second code block and the paragraph just above that -- it appeared there 18 minutes ago :)

Comment: Can you explain my why i get an error in this line, "intent.putExtra("id", item.mId);" ? It says "item cannot be resolved to a variable" ?

Comment: Could you update your *question* with the code you have now? You might have missed the line that starts with `RowData item = `.

Comment: You indeed forgot to copy this line at the beginning of your `onListItemClick()` method from my answer:
`RowData item = (RowData) getListAdapter().getItem(position);`

Comment: You are so right, I dont know how I could forget that. I have no errors now, but i still dont see how to open different activity´s. No matter which item i click the same activity just opens?

Comment: Your `NewActivity` does not do anything with the ID it gets from `getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");` -- if you want to show something different depending on the ID, you have to implement it :)

Comment: Could you give me a hint on how to :) ?

Comment: I might be able to, if you add to your question what exactly you want to display in this `NewActivity`.

Comment: Okay. In my MainActivity I have a ListView, as You already know. In this List my plan is to have about 20 different rows/items, whit a small text and a image. Then I need to open a Activity when a row/item is pushed, that will make it around 20 different Activity´s, and in each Activity I just what to show some text. Hope You understand.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. But given the ID of the item you clicked, *what text* do you want to display in `NewActivity`?

Comment: Just some text from a xml layout

Comment: But how do you want this text to change depending on which list item the user clicked? Are there different layouts, different texts, different ...? Please add a sample of what you want to display in `NewActivity` to your question and explain what exactly should be displayed when a user clicks on a list item.

Comment: Lets say my list have 10 items, item 1, item 2, item 3 and so on. When item 1 is clicked i what that to open a new activity, let call that NewActivityOne, and this activity will refer to a layout with some text called layoutone. Item 2 will also open a new activity, NewActivityTwo, it will refer to a new layout called layouttwo. And thats how I want it to be for all my items.

Comment: I updated my answer one last time. I'm sorry, but this is getting too long. If you need more help, please post a new question, referencing this one so people can read up on it.